# How to increase efficiency by using for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner java programmer and I am making a simple TicTacToe game using 2D arrays and these are my if statements to check if player 1, or player 2 has won. I believe that this can be simplified by using for loop(s) however I do not understand how to use that method.

```
if ((grid[0][0] == 1 && grid[0][1] == 1 && grid[0][2] == 1)
            || (grid[1][0] == 1 && grid[1][1] == 1 && grid[1][2] == 1)
            || (grid[2][0] == 1 && grid[2][1] == 1 && grid[2][2] == 1)
            || (grid[0][0] == 1 && grid[1][1] == 1 && grid[2][2] == 1)
            || (grid[0][2] == 1 && grid[1][1] == 1 && grid[2][0] == 1)
            || (grid[0][0] == 1 && grid[1][0] == 1 && grid[2][0] == 1)
            || (grid[0][1] == 1 && grid[1][1] == 1 && grid[2][1] == 1)
            || (grid[0][2] == 1 && grid[1][2] == 1 && grid[2][2] == 1)
            && won == false) {
        title.setText("X wins!");
        won = true;
    } else if ((grid[0][0] == 2 && grid[0][1] == 2 && grid[0][2] == 2)
            || (grid[1][0] == 2 && grid[1][1] == 2 && grid[1][2] == 2)
            || (grid[2][0] == 2 && grid[2][1] == 2 && grid[2][2] == 2)
            || (grid[0][0] == 2 && grid[1][1] == 2 && grid[2][2] == 2)
            || (grid[0][2] == 2 && grid[1][1] == 2 && grid[2][0] == 2)
            || (grid[0][0] == 2 && grid[1][0] == 2 && grid[2][0] == 2)
            || (grid[0][1] == 2 && grid[1][1] == 2 && grid[2][1] == 2)
            || (grid[0][2] == 2 && grid[1][2] == 2 && grid[2][2] == 2)
            && won == false) {
        title.setText("O wins!");
        won = true;
    }
```

Below is the modified code that uses far less if statments and conditions.

```
public static boolean hasWon(int[][] grid) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= 2; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < grid.length; b++) {
            // Checking for win in horizontal, then vertical, then diagonal
            if (grid[b][0] == a && grid[b][1] == a && grid[b][2] == a) {
                won = true;
            } else if (grid[0][b] == a && grid[1][b] == a && grid[2][b] == a) {
                won = true;
            } else if ((grid[0][0] == a && grid[1][1] == a && grid[2][2] == a
                    || (grid[0][2] == a && grid[1][1] == a && grid[2][0] == a))) {
                won = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not covered all conditions. And (true or false) is easier than (1 or 2), I think.

Comment: Use two `for-loops` and put statement `if` and `else-if` inside the inner loop.

Comment: Code now meets all conditions. Will work on a for loop solution to clean it up.

Comment: What happens if (row 0 is all 1) and (row 1 is all 2) ?

Comment: If row 0 (top row) is all 1, X wins, if row 1 (middle row) is all 2, O wins.

Comment: Then if no matching lines, which wins?

Comment: I have not added that yet. However, if all moves have been made with no winner, I will have the game reset and print "Cat's Game!".

Comment: So, it is filtered before this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126430/discussion-between-jzbakos-and-toris).

Comment: Changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to help you reach a solution on your own I'll give you some hints for now.

Hint #1: Think about what it means to win. A player must get 3 of their tokens in a row - horizontal, vertical, or diagonal. Think about how that can be represented in your program.

Hint #2: Think about how you can break the problem into smaller more manageable pieces. Think about what each winning scenario has in common and separate that logic into a method that you can call multiple times.

Hint #3: Consider what makes each winning scenario unique and how you might use your `grid` to produce a representation of the spaces you want to examine that is easier to check for a win.

If you're not sure about how for loops work or other aspects of the Java Language you can find tutorials on [Oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the OP with my new solution that works.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you want to add an additional level of challenge just to stretch yourself a little more you could consider the following: How would you write your code generically so that you could change the board to a rectangle of any size?

Comment: Would I set the value of the columns and rows for the button array and grid array equal to a configurable valuable declared at the top/beginning?

Comment: Yes, that's how you would begin. You'll also need to modify any logic that depends on having 3 rows and 3 columns to be more generic.

Comment: You also have to decide how you want to handle diagonals when the board is not square. For simplicity you could just decide that you're going to impose a rule that only two of them are valid - it's really up to you since a rectangular board is completely outside the normal rules.

Comment: I think I will start by using one value only, forcing the shape to be a square.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126483/discussion-between-d-b-and-jzbakos).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. For loops are the way to go. Here is one way you could implement it.

```
    public class tictactoe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] grid = {{1, 2, 1},
                {1, 2, 1},
                {2, 0, 1}};
        boolean won = hasWon(grid);


    }

    public static boolean hasWon(int[][] grid){
        for (int player = 1; player <= 2; player++){
            boolean playerWon = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                //Horizonal win
                playerWon = (grid[i][0] == player && grid[i][1] == player && grid[i][2] == player) || playerWon;

                //Vertical Win
                playerWon = (grid[0][i] == player && grid[1][i] == player && grid[i][2] == player) || playerWon;

            }
            //Diagonal Win
            playerWon = (grid[0][0] == player && grid[1][1] == player && grid[2][2] == player) || playerWon;
            playerWon = (grid[0][2] == player && grid[1][1] == player && grid[2][0] == player) || playerWon;

            if(playerWon){
                if(player == 1){
                    System.out.println("X wins!");
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("O wins!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //neither have won
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer for the question. (as this is not "check all at once" style)

To simplify,
1. Check when a cell is clicked.
2. Condition depends on the place of a cell which is clicked and who clicked the cell.
3. If someone wins, end the game.

---

code sample

```
// Part of codes.(not tested.)
// Each cell has three states (0, 1, or 2)

int player = 1; // (Not written here but) switch this each turn (1 or 2)

// In some place (activity.onCreate() etc)
{
    // For on click event(0, 0)
    cell_0_0.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                grid[0][0] = player;
                final boolean isEnd = checkEnd_0_0();
                if (isEnd) {
                    // Call some function to end the game.
                    // Calling title.setText() in game end function maybe good.
                    // (as not needed to write many times.)
                    if (player == 1) {
                        title.setText("X wins!");
                    } else {
                        title.setText("O wins!");
                    }
                } else {
                    switchPlayer(); // Not written in this code.
                }
            }
        };
    );
    ...
}

// Call this on cell(0, 0) click event
// Returns true if someone wins.
boolean checkEnd_0_0() {
    // Omit checking grid[0][0] is 1 or 2 as it is clear.
    // Check horizontal.
    if (grid[0][1] == player) {
        if (grid[0][2] == player) {
            return true; // This is the case shown in question.
        }
    }
    // Check other cases (vertical, diagonal)
    ...
    // No match.
    return false;
}
```